# "Собрал компьютер" — какой вид связи?

Tags: синтаксис

Собрал (компьютер) сам - это согласование, управление или примыкание?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего примыкание.

Comment: "Примыкание - вид
подчинительной связи, при
котором зависимость
подчиненного слова
выражается не
грамматически, а
лексически (по смыслу),
порядком слов и
интонацией. Примыкают
только неизменяемые
знаменательные части речи:
наречие, инфинитив,
деепричастие, простая
сравнительная степень
прилагательного (дети
постарше), неизменяемое
прилагательное (цвет хаки),
существительное –
несогласованное
приложение (в газете
«Известия»),
притяжательные
местоимения его, её, их." [Ссылка](http://www.gramma.ru/EXM/?id=4.38)

Comment: Смотря где разбирается словосочетание. Если в школе - да, а если в вузе, то всё намного сложнее, бывает ещё и падежное примыкание(сильное и слабое, предложное и беспредложное), тогда примыкают существительные с предлогом.

Comment: Примыкание не доказано и пример не разобран. У [Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/63.htm) формулировка такая же : " Примыкают наречие, прилагательное в
сравнительной степени, деепричастие,
инфинитив, притяжательные
местоимения 3 лица и другие
**неизменяемые слова и формы**". Без ссылки и разбора утверждение о "примыкании" - просто мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Неплохо бы иметь всё предложение. Если там нет другого подлежащего, тогда САМ-подлежащее, это не словосочетание,а грамматическая основа,связь - координация.

Если "Я (или ОН) собрал компьютер сам", то примыкание, потому что сам  = самостоятельно, слово САМ не меняется, т.е. не управляется и не согласуется.

Comment: Почему не меняется? Пришлось собрать самому, самой...

Comment: Но это совсем другое предложение, здесь пришлось кому? -самому - управление, а собрал как? - сам, падежный вопрос невозможен, как и какой?

Comment: Ирина, не могли бы Вы дать предложение, в котором вычленили данное словосочетание?Нужно разобраться,вычленяется ли оно вообще.Это, действительно, синкретичный член предложения, согласующийся с подлежащим в роде, числе, падеже,или координирующийся со сказуемым в роде и числе, или примыкающий к сказуемому, если в значении наречия САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО. Тогда форма муж.рода(как и жен., и средн. рода)будет застывшей. Я собрал сам. Ты собрал сам. Он собрал сам.Собираю сам. Буду собирать сам. - слово не меняется.(Слово в этом значении, а не часть речи определит. местоимение)

Comment: Если Вам необходимо дать  характеристику словосочетания СОБРАЛ САМ, то это будет простое свободное глагольное сочетание с главным словом  - глаголом прош.вр. 3 лица ед.ч. муж.рода, выполн. роль сказуемого.Зависимое слово - синкретичный член предложения, выраженный застывшей формой определительного мест. муж. рода ед.ч. в значении наречия "самостоятельно", который согласуется с подлежащим(если оно есть)или координируется в роде и числе со сказуемым, будучи подлежащим, и одновременно примыкает к сказуемому.

Answer (score 0):

Собрал ( что?) компьютер. 
Здесь - управление, т.к падежный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю, что надо определить вид грамматической  связи в словосочетании "собрал компьютер"? Разумеется, это управление, так как зависимое слово является существительным, при изменении главного оно не меняется. А вот "сам собрал" - это уже предикативная связь. Всё разногласие, по - моему, из -за того, что в заголовке вопроса указано одно словосочетание "собрал компьютер", а в самой формулировке вопроса "компьютер"  взят в скобки, получается, что нужно определять связь в словосочетании "собрал сам". Это НЕКОРРЕКТНАЯ формулировка вопроса.